# How to achieve this type of parallax effect in LibGdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

I am working in a game like Geometry dash in **libGdx** , I also got parallax background , but i want to achieve "front" parallax like this example in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFH-uEGWio4).

1. I have to use different layers?
2. What is the trick in the video?

   I hope someone give me a idea c: here is my actual parallax background
   [parallax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9oxz.png)

Comment: The easiest way is to simply increase the X and Y movements of any objects in the front row by a desired factor. For example: `FrontX += PlayerVelocityX * 1.5f;`

Comment: Alternate method is to use a separate camera for each layer. Scale the movement of the cameras that aren't on the gameplay layer.